# Load data from URL parameters faster

Tags: javascript

Assuming I am loading a web with `domain.com/1/?nick=lili`

Right now I am including in my `html` - multiple files, in one of them I do :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         let path = window.location.href ;
         let nick = path.split('=')[1];
         getData(nick,loadUI);

});
```

Using fast servers (`Google's Firebase`) I still get quite a delay, about 1-2 seconds while at this time the page *is loaded with placeholders* so no data, and the experience is not good.

I do not want to put a loader UI element, *but to load faster*.

Is there anywhere else in the code that I can put this to make things faster? (assuming I also need to load Google's server API on the body).

Removing all of this to the `head` should work better?

Comment: What exactly does `getData` need to succeed? Does the page need to be loaded when it's called to run? Does the page need to be loaded when it finishes?

Comment: Thanks. getData needs nothing, only to initialize the Google API's and the parameter from URL. So when someone open the page, all html placeholders (texts and photos) are loaded, then I need to fill them with data from DB - as fast as possible, so I read the url parameter, go to server, and load back all data into the placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window.location.href` will be populated on pageload - there's no need to wait before checking it. Since `getData` does not need any data from the page in order to *start* the request, you can move it outside of the `$(document).ready(`, and even move it up to the top of the document, in the `<head>`, before any other scripts have run or elements have loaded. This ensures that the request gets sent out as fast as possible.

But

> when someone open the page, all html placeholders (texts and photos) are loaded, then I need to fill them with data from DB

Because you need the page to be loaded when the request comes back, you can't just call `getData` alone, in the rare case that the page hasn't finished loading by then. So, if you change `getData` to return a Promise that resolves to the desired data, you could use `Promise.all` to wait for both the data *and* for the page to be loaded, after which you can populate the page elements:

```
Promise.all([
  getData(nick,loadUI),
  new Promise(res => window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', res))
])
  .then(([data]) => {
    // Populate page with data from request
  });
```

Comment: Yes, before any other `<script>` tags. Make sure that `getData` returns a Promise that resolves to the requested data.